# multiple file upload sql/php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to upload multiple files and then insert the files names in mysql db
my problem is with inserting the names it only store the last file name

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['file']['size']);$i++){
    if(strstr($_FILES['file']['type'][$i], 'image')!==false){
        $file = 'uploads/'.time().' - '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$file);
        $na=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        $sql="INSERT INTO img (img_name) VALUES ('$na');";
    }
}
```

notice that all the files are uploaded successfully

Comment: If you indent your code it's a lot clearer what's happening

Comment: Are you calling mysql_query() function outside your for loop? If yes then you know the solution now...

Comment: I see you setting `$sql`, but when do you run that query?

Comment: looks like you are actually running the query after the loop. Try `$sql .="query here;";`

Comment: @Nic: That probably won't work.  PHP doesn't like you running multiple queries in one call.

Comment: @Jay yeah i have an error chick after the loop 
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

Comment: thank you it worked !!! by just removing the error chick and put it inside the loop

Comment: Mmm. You could add it in an array and do a `foreach` loop after. but I guess adding `mysql_query()` inside your main loop is better as the accepted solution shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['file']['size']);$i++){
    if(strstr($_FILES['file']['type'][$i], 'image')!==false){
        $file = 'uploads/'.time().' - '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$file);
        $na=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        $sql="INSERT INTO img (img_name) VALUES ('$na');";
    }
}
```

you are just creating a string and storing some value. you have not executed it .. 
Say $str = "apple"; Its just a declaration. I presume you have executed the query after the loop. Say you have 10 files. loop gets executed 10 times and $na has the last filename which gets inserted.

Soln: move your execute query inside the for loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['file']['size']);$i++){
    if(strstr($_FILES['file']['type'][$i], 'image')!==false){
        $file = 'uploads/'.time().' - '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$file);
        $na=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        $sql="INSERT INTO img (img_name) VALUES ('$na');";
        mysql_query($con,$sql); // note: $con is your connection string
    }
}
```