# PHP Multiple file upload and store the names in Database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, pdo

I am PHP beginner and building my own practice project (I have thought it something like used car sale online site)
My problem is very similar to [multiple file upload sql/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907670/multiple-file-upload-sql-php) and [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php?rq=1)

Here are list of my problems
I want to upload image in a directory and store it's name in database. So far below code is working fine (if I upload 1 file). I am trying to add 3 more file input option so that user can upload upto 4 images.

So far trying different codes available in stackoverflow and other online sites, I have been able to atleast upload the multiple files in my directory. But the real problem is that I don't know how I would store the name of the file in database .

(In most of the tutorials and suggestions, I found I should use 1 input file type with multiple attributes or name equals array like file[] and run foreach loop. But I couldn't figure out how would go ahead and get the file name of each input and store it in database.

Below are my code for the reference.

```
    //this is my form.addVehicle.php file to process the form

    <?php
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "../uploads/");
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  {
    $name = "default.jpg";
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["myFile"]['tmp_name'])) {
        $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];
        if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
            exit;
        }
        // ensure a safe filename
        $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);
        // don't overwrite an existing file
        $i = 0;
        $parts = pathinfo($name);
        while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
            $i++;
            $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
        }
        // preserve file from temporary directory
        $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
            UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
        if (!$success) {
            echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
            exit;
        }
        // set proper permissions on the new file
        chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
    }
    include_once ('../class/class.Vehicle.php');

    $vehicle = new Vehicle(
        $_POST['make_id'],
        $_POST['yearMade'],
        $_POST['mileage'],
        $_POST['transmission'],
        $_POST['price'],
        $_POST['zone_name'],
        $name,
        $_POST['description']
    );
}
?>      
    //To give a try, tested is_uploaded_file condition four different times with //different file name id like myFile1,myFile2...and path variable as $name1, //$name2...and it works as I want it to be...but I'm sure that' not the correct //way to do it..

    //This is my class file with name class.Vehicle.php 

    include_once('class.pdoDbConnnection.php');

    class Vehicle{
        private  $make_id;
        private  $yearMade;
        private  $mileage;
        private  $transmission;
        private  $price;
        private  $zone_name;
        private  $image_path;
        private  $description;

        public function __construct($make_id, $yearMade, $mileage, $transmission, $price, $zone_name, $image_path, $description){

            $this->make_id = $make_id;
            $this->yearMade = $yearMade;
            $this->mileage = $mileage;
            $this->transmission= $transmission;
            $this->price = $price;
            $this->zone_name = $zone_name;
            $this->image_path = $image_path;
            $this->description = $description;

            try{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO cars (car_id, make_id, yearmade, mileage, transmission, price, zone_name,image_path, description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $pdo = new DBConnection();
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array(NULL,$this->make_id,$this->yearMade,$this->mileage,$this->transmission,$this->price,$this->zone_name,$this->image_path,$this->description));

            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    Here are my mySql table columns (I want to insert file names in the column..while displaying it in the client side, I'm using it this way: <img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="../uploads/<?php echo $row['image_path'] ?>">
    car_id , make_id , zone_id, yearmade, mileage, transmission, price, image_path, image_path1, image_path2, image_path3, description


    This is my client side form to add new cars....
    ..................
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="../includes/form.addVehicle.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    .....................
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Image</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="myFile" name="myFile">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Image</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="myFile1" name="myFile2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Image</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="myFile3" name="myFile3">
                    </div>
                </div>
    ..............
```

Comment: Since I'm PHP beginner, I would appreciate if anyone would comment or provide feedback on the code that may not be related to my issue..for example whether my approach is correct or not, if there's anything wrong I  'm doing in my class file or logic...thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Finally I ended up with the following code.

P.S. Thanks to [@Andy-Brahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601882/andy-braham) insight at [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php?lq=1)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$uploads_dir = '../test_uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        // I don't want to overwrite the existing file
        $i = 0;
        $parts = pathinfo($name);
        while (file_exists($uploads_dir . "/" . $name)) {
            $i++;
            $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
        }
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
    // Test to see if I get the uploaded file name which i want to insert into database table column.
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES['pictures']['name'][0]);
    echo"</br></br>";
    print_r($_FILES['pictures']['name'][1]);
    echo"</br></br>";
    print_r($_FILES['pictures']['name'][2]);
    echo"</br></br>";
    print_r($_FILES['pictures']['name'][3]);
    echo"</br></br>";
    echo "</pre>";
    // test succeeds . Now I guess I can do something like $picture0 = $_FILES['pictures']['name'][0]);
    // and insert $picture0,$picture1...into database..
    // Am I doing everything correctly?


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will make example, you just adapt it for yourself.

```
    <form action="file_reciever.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit" name="submission" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

the PHP goes (`file_reciever.php`):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submission'] && $_POST['submission'] != null) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
            //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

            //Make sure we have a filepath
            if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
                //Setup our new file path
                $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

                    //Handle other code here

                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @CJ  : Thankyou very much providing a valuable insight.